# Download m3u8 from URL using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, m3u8

I started learning web scraping with Python. Currently, I would like to download a video of the Japanese Diet. (https://www.shugiintv.go.jp/jp/index.php?ex=VL&deli_id=40124&media_type=)

The video seems to have a mechanism to call chunklist.m3u8 from playlist.m3u8 and then call the ts files described in chunklist.m3u8 in order.

I want to download the contents from the playlist.m3u8 URL first, then call chunklist.m3u8 to download the ts files in order and concat.

However, I tried to download Playlist.m3u8, but it didn't produce the text I expected.

Also, the sample URL of playlist.m3u8 is here↓

http://hlsvod.shugiintv.go.jp/vod/_definst_/amlst:2011/2011-1207-0900-12/playlist.m3u8

code:

```
import requests

url = "http://hlsvod.shugiintv.go.jp/vod/_definst_/amlst:2011/2011-1207-0900-12/playlist.m3u8"
res = requests.get(url)
print(res.text)
```

excepted text:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=564000,NAME="500k",RESOLUTION=640x360
chunklist_w60346572_b564000_t64NTAwaw==.m3u8
```

actual text:

```
<html><head><title>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Perpetual Bundle Unlimited Edition 4.7.7 build20181108145350</title></head><body>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Perpetual Bundle Unlimited Edition 4.7.7 build20181108145350</body></html>
```

I think there is a problem with the colon in the URL, but I don't have a clear solution. I would like to know how to avoid URL issues and successfully download the text in playlist.m3u8. Thanks.

Version:

Python 3.7.9

requests 2.25.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your url:

```
>>> url = "http://hlsvod.shugiintv.go.jp/vod/_definst_/amlst:2011/2011-1207-0900-12/playlist.m3u8"
>>> res = requests.get(url)
>>> res.request.url
'https://hlsvod.shugiintv.go.jp/vod/_definst_/amlst:2011/2011-1207-0900-12/playlist.m3u8%20'
```

See the "%20" in the end?

I am not really sure how you got it wrong, but copy-paste this should work:

```
url = 'https://hlsvod.shugiintv.go.jp/vod/_definst_/amlst:2011/2011-1207-0900-12/playlist.m3u8'
```

Comment: Oh, thank you.! I was worried about my mistake, but your answer seems to solve it. It seems that Colon didn't matter. I will investigate separately why I made a mistake.Thank you very much!!!